# ERROR apt: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0: undefined symbol: _ZN11pkgDepCache24IncreaseActionGroupLevelEv

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

At first I had this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapt-pkg5.0:amd64:
 dpkg (1.21.1ubuntu2.1) breaks libapt-pkg5.0 (<< 1.7~b) and is installed.
  Version of libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 to be configured is 1.2.29.
```

But after several attempts to fix this problem by trying several forums my problem got worse.
And now apt itself is broken, with the error message:

```
apt: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0: undefined symbol: _ZN11pkgDepCache24IncreaseActionGroupLevelEv, version APTPKG_6.0
```

dpkg still works fine. But I did not find the corresponding package to fix the problem

I've been trying to fix it for a while now but I really can't find it. I'd be really grateful if someone knew how to fix it.

Comment: How did you get here? Did you manually install some deb packages you've downloaded from repositories manually? What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: @popey Yes, according to some messages I've seen, I tried to manually install libapt-pkg5.0_1.6.1_amd64.deb and then libapt-pkg6.0_2.2.4_amd64.deb in connection with the first error I had, but it didn't change anything.

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2

Comment: The current version of libapt-pkg6.0 for focal (22.04) is 2.0.2ubuntu0. which you can find via https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=libapt-pkg - I'd instal that one, and any other packages which you have erroneously downgraded.

Comment: @popey Thank you, this and a few other modifications have helped me to fix all my problems